# How to get and print attributes in meta tags using simple_html_dom

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Ok, I am at a loss here. I am new to programming, have Googled for this relentlessly, and have even asked about this here but to no avail, so I am trying again now that I am a little better researched.

I need to retrieve the text from what is inside the "content" attribute from this line of code:

```
<meta property='og:title' content="title goes here" />
```

This is the code that I have so far that is not working:

```
//saves the URL as HTML
$movie_html = file_get_html($movie_url);

//finds the title within the HTML
$movie_title_meta = $movie_html->find("meta[name=og:title]");
$movie_title = $movie_title_meta->content;

//prints the score
var_dump($movie_title_meta);
```

What I want that code to give me is:

```
title goes here
```

But instead I get a NULL error. I have a feeling a var_dump() is not actually what I want to be doing, but a simple echo() is returning errors also. I just have no idea what to do at this point, so any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser by David Walsh...
http://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications

Comment: Does using that require me adding anything else to my server or can I use it with what I have already?

Comment: Never mind. It's part of simple_html_dom that I was already using. And it works!!! Hurrah! I shall be eternally grateful.